# SQL query that calculates, on a daily basis, the absolute number of active users, and the percentage of active users among all users

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, data-warehouse

I have to build a SQL query, ideally SQLlite syntax, that calculates
on a daily basis, the absolute number of active users, and the percentage of active users among all users. An active user is defined as a user to be active one some day X, if the user listened to at least one song in the time interval [X-6 days,X] . The result should adhere to the following schema꞉
1 row per day
3 columns꞉ (date, number_active_users, percentage_active_users)

We have the following Schema:

```
-- Tables
-- tracks dimension
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tracks(
    recording_msid        TEXT   NOT NULL,
    track_name            TEXT   NOT NULL,
    release_msid          TEXT   NOT NULL,
    release_name          TEXT   NOT NULL,
    release_mbid          TEXT   DEFAULT NULL,
    recording_mbid        TEXT   DEFAULT NULL,
    isrc                  TEXT   DEFAULT NULL,
    track_number          TEXT   DEFAULT NULL,
    track_mbid            TEXT   DEFAULT NULL,
    work_mbids            TEXT   DEFAULT NULL,
    dedup_tag             TEXT   DEFAULT NULL,
    tags                  TEXT   DEFAULT NULL,
    release_group_mbid    TEXT   DEFAULT NULL,
    artist_names          TEXT   DEFAULT NULL,
    discnumber            INT    DEFAULT NULL,
    release_artist_name   TEXT   DEFAULT NULL,
    release_artist_names  TEXT   DEFAULT NULL,
    rating                INT    DEFAULT NULL,
    source                TEXT   DEFAULT NULL,
    track_length          INT    DEFAULT NULL,
    albumartist           TEXT   DEFAULT NULL,
    totaldiscs            INT    DEFAULT NULL,
    totaltracks           INT    DEFAULT NULL,
    choosen_by_user       TEXT   DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY           (recording_msid,track_name)
);

-- users dimension
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
    user_name                TEXT      PRIMARY KEY,
    spotify_id               TEXT      DEFAULT NULL,
    spotify_album_artist_ids TEXT      DEFAULT NULL,
    spotify_album_id         INTEGER   DEFAULT NULL,
    spotify_artist_ids       TEXT      DEFAULT NULL
);

-- artists dimension
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS artists(
    artist_msid     TEXT  PRIMARY KEY,
    artist_name     TEXT  NOT NULL,
    artist_mbids    TEXT  DEFAULT NULL
);

-- fact table user history
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_history(
    listened_at         NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    track_name          TEXT NOT NULL,
    recording_msid      TEXT NOT NULL,
    user_name           TEXT NOT NULL,
    artist_msid         TEXT NOT NULL,
    duration_ms         INT DEFAULT NULL,
    duration            INT DEFAULT NULL,
    listening_from      NUMERIC DEFAULT NULL,
    "date"              NUMERIC DEFAULT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(track_name) REFERENCES tracks(track_name),
    FOREIGN KEY(recording_msid) REFERENCES tracks(recording_msid),
    FOREIGN KEY(user_name) REFERENCES users(user_name),
    FOREIGN KEY(artist_msid) REFERENCES artists(artist_msid)
);
```

Any help or simple pointing in the right direction will do. Thanks! Some alterations to the schema are also possible

This is what I tried but it gives only one date group

```
with user_groups as(
select date(listened_at, 'unixepoch','localtime') as dt, count(user_name) as cnt
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date(listened_at, 'unixepoch','localtime'))
                as row_no
                FROM user_history GROUP by date(listened_at, 'unixepoch','localtime')
           )
select dt as date, cnt as active_users, cnt/SUM(cnt) as percentage
from user_groups
where row_no between 1 and 6;
```

Answer (score 1):

try self joins. I cannot write an SQL but know that this can be easily solved by creating a 6 way self join. Self join works the same way in SQLlite as in other databases

Comment: Thank you for answering! If you don't know how to write the self joins, feel free to add any helpful link for the same, it will be very helpful to others.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).